# Edición de tablas + mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

espero puedan ayudarme un poco con la siguiente situación que estoy presentando.

Trato de editar las columnas de mi tabla, pero al editarlas quisiera que estas con solo dar un clic fuera de las celdas se mandaran automáticamente a la Base de datos que previamente fue diseñada.
Mi tabla es la siguiente en la cual primero pinto los datos que tengo en cada columna de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a código esto es lo que por ahora estoy manejando con respecto a las celdas de la tabla.

```php
<td class="tdResult">
    <?php
    $sqlCon_obj = "SELECT contacto FROM metaa WHERE edat = 'General'";
    $resCon_obj = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlCon_obj);
    while ($verCon_obj = mysqli_fetch_row($resCon_obj)) {
        $datosCon_obj = $verCon_obj[0];
    }
    ?>
    <textarea><?= $datosCon_obj; ?></textarea>
</td>
<td class="tdResult">
    <?php
    $sqlEnt_obj = "SELECT entrevista FROM metaa WHERE edat = 'General'";
    $resEnt_obj = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlEnt_obj);
    while ($verEnt_obj = mysqli_fetch_row($resEnt_obj)) {
        $datosEnt_obj = $verEnt_obj[0];
    }
    ?>
    <textarea><?= $datosEnt_obj; ?></textarea>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas Ajax para enviar las consultas a un php que haga el cambio.
PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor, javascript del lado del cliente por lo que si queres hacer esto sin refrescar la pagina necesitas Ajax, sino podes recargar la pagina haciendo un formulario html que se envie cuando cambies un valor. Te paso lo que haria yo

HTML

```
<div id="datos"></div>

<script>
    function actualizar(tipo){
        var valor = $("#"+tipo).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'grabar.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: {"tipo":tipo,
                "valor":valor
            },
            success: function(respuesta){
               cargar();
            }
        });
    }
    
    function cargar(){
         $.ajax({
            url: 'consultar.php',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(respuesta){
               $("#datos").html(respuesta);
            }
        });

    }
    cargar();
</script>
```

grabar.php

```
//agregar conexion
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$valor = $_POST['valor'];

//agregar update
```

consultar.php

```
<td class="tdResult">
    <?php
    $sqlCon_obj = "SELECT contacto FROM metaa WHERE edat = 'General'";
    $resCon_obj = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlCon_obj);
    while ($verCon_obj = mysqli_fetch_row($resCon_obj)) {
        $datosCon_obj = $verCon_obj[0];
    }
    ?>
    <textarea id="contactos" onchange="actualizar('contactos')"><?= $datosCon_obj; ?></textarea>
</td>
<td class="tdResult">
    <?php
    $sqlEnt_obj = "SELECT entrevista FROM metaa WHERE edat = 'General'";
    $resEnt_obj = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlEnt_obj);
    while ($verEnt_obj = mysqli_fetch_row($resEnt_obj)) {
        $datosEnt_obj = $verEnt_obj[0];
    }
    ?>
    <textarea id="entrevistas" onchange="actualizar('entrevistas')"><?= $datosEnt_obj; ?></textarea>
</td>
```

Tene en cuenta que para usar ajax vas a tener importar jquery

Una cosita mas, si la consulta solo va a retornarte un valor hacela asi. no tiene sentido un while ahi

```
$sqlCon_obj = "SELECT contacto FROM metaa WHERE edat = 'General'";
$resCon_obj = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlCon_obj);

list($datosCon_obj) = mysqli_fetch_row($resCon_obj);
```

Comment: Agradezco tu pronta respuesta, ya intente hacerlo como me indicas pero en el ajax no me jala el php que estoy colocando para que haga el update.

Comment: Te fijaste que te tira por consola? confirmado que no estas llegando al php desde la consulta ajax? Te paso la referencia que tenes que poner al final de la etiqueta body para llamar jquery
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>